# How to get previous user's page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have update action ( Devise gem ) and I need to redirect to different page depends on previous page.

I tried to check previous page like that:

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
 logger.info("request:referer: " + request.referer)
 logger.info("paypal_path: " + paypal_path)
  if request.referer == paypal_path
   show_code_path
  else
   edit_user_registration_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work. Goes to else branch.

**From console**

```
     request:referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/paypal
     paypal_path: /paypal
     Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/edit.13
```

**EDIT:**

When I go to paypal_path from home page gives me nil and when it redirects me after paypal_path to edit_user_registration_path(current_user) gives me RIGHT previous URL - .../paypal

What I can do to make it work ?

Comment: can you post the content of request.referer?

Comment: @Flo, in paypal page or edit_user_registration ?

Comment: @Flo, look in the question please. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the current page like this: 
        current_page?(:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name')

Comment: I need to do it in controller. When I'm using `current_page?` gives me `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Ok after chatting we found a way:

```
if request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://#{request.env["HTTP_HOST"]}/paypal"
  show_code_path 
else 
  edit_user_registration_path(current_user) 
end
```

Comment: thx.  you can use: request.path instead of request.referer which will give you the current url without base url

Comment: Like this ? - `if request.path == paypal_path`

Comment: like: if request.path == paypal_path

Comment: hmm. can you post the output from request.path like: logger.info("request path: " + request.path)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17589/discussion-between-flo-and-denmed)